# AttributeError at /edit/ 'RequestContext' object has no attribute 'flatten' (Django 1.6.7)

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I have working project on Django 1.7 and now I had to downgrade Django version to 1.6.7. Now all seems work ok except one page where I get above mentioned error. The issue traceback pointed to crispy-forms and it exactly due to django version because as soon as I upgrade to django==1.7 all works again.
Anybody knows how to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the flatten property was introduced to the Context object in the version Django==1.7.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context.flatten

You may need to downgrade your django-crispy-forms version.

Comment: Thanks, i thought about it. What version do you recommend?

Comment: nice! @AndriyKravchenko